# Combine 2 SELECT statements with filled gaps

Tags: mysql, join, right-join

I have this SELECT:

```
SELECT
    m.`maschine-name` AS 'byMaschine',
    q.`mname` AS 'byMName'
FROM
    `qualitaet` q
INNER JOIN
    maschinen m ON m.maschine = q.maschine
WHERE
    q.`status`='1'
GROUP BY
    concat(q.maschine, q.mname)
```

and get this result:

```
| maschine-name | mname |
|     TYP 1     |   0   |
|     TYP 2     |   3   |
|     TYP 2     |   4   |
|     TYP 3     |   0   |
|     TYP 4     |   0   |
```

see SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/454cd8/1)

Then i have nearly the same SELECT with additional COUNT and Datefilter:

```
SELECT
    m.`maschine-name` AS 'byMaschine',
    q.`mname` AS 'byMName',
COUNT(*) AS 'total'
FROM
    `qualitaet` q
INNER JOIN
    maschinen m ON m.maschine = q.maschine
WHERE
    q.`created`>=NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY
AND
    q.`status`='1'
GROUP BY
    concat(q.maschine, q.mname)
```

and get this result:

```
| maschine-name | mname | total |
|     TYP 2     |   3   |   1   |
|     TYP 3     |   0   |   2   |
```

see SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/454cd8/2)

The 2nd SELECT doesn't give me all information. I need a mix from both SELECTS

The 2nd SELECT should look like this result:

```
| maschine-name | mname | total |
|     TYP 1     |   0   |   0   |
|     TYP 2     |   3   |   1   |
|     TYP 2     |   4   |   0   |
|     TYP 3     |   0   |   2   |
|     TYP 4     |   0   |   0   |
```

Is it possible to RIGHT JOIN with 2 SELECTS? Or is there another way to get the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT m.`maschine-name` AS byMaschine, q.`mname` AS byMName,
       sum(q.created >= NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY) as Total
FROM qualitaet q INNER JOIN
     maschinen m
    ON m.maschine = q.maschine
WHERE q.status = '1'
GROUP BY q.maschine, q.mname;
```

Other suggestions:

- There is no need to concatenate the grouping columns in the `GROUP BY` -- unless you really, really intend to do this (which I doubt).
- If `status` is numeric, don't use single quotes for the constant.
- Don't use single quotes for column aliases.  In fact, your aliases don't need any quotes at all.

Comment: Wow! That was fast! And works perfect! Thank you! HAPPY NEW YEAR ;)

Comment: I found a little problem. i cleared all q.status fields to 1 and added only 1 row with status=2. When i now select with satus=2 i get only one TYP. Do you have another idea that also status=2 have all TYP listed? see the sqlfiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/937d4/1

Comment: @bernie . . . There is no column called `TYP` in the question, so I don't understand your comment.  Perhaps you should ask another question.